# How to get nginx phase on which handler was called

Tags: c, http, nginx, webserver, internals

I'm writing my own Nginx HTTP module. I'm registering module's handler on two phases: `NGX_HTTP_SERVER_REWRITE_PHASE` and `NGX_HTTP_PREACCESS_PHASE`. The logic is pretty much the same on each phase therefore it's unnecessarily to make two different handler-functions, but the the logic is still slightly different depending on the phase on which the handler was called.

The question is if it available somehow to determine the phase on which the handler-function was called inside this handler-function?